# `require': cannot load such file -- mongo (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rspec, rubygems

`require': cannot load such file -- mongo (LoadError)

Not sure why I am receiving this error. All the other gems that I use work fine. The top of my rspec test looks like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spec_helper.rb'
require 'base64'
require 'json'
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'mysql2'
require 'mongo'
```

'mongo' however works in irb:

```
irb => require 'mongo'
true
```

When I use it in a script it also works. Just not in my rspec test. My file structure looks like:
automation/test/spec/lib/test_spec.rb Though, it doesn't seem to matter where I run the test from. I am also using RVM, but like I said before all the other gems are working so I don't believe it to be a path issue.

For the versioning comparison here is a copy of my gem list:

```
bson (1.9.2)
bson_ext (1.9.2)
mongo (1.9.2)
rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.4)
rspec-expectations (2.14.0)
rspec-mocks (2.14.4, 2.14.1)
```

Comment: I guess it is a ruby version issue

Comment: How are you launching your tests? Are you using Bundler?

Comment: I cd into the test folder and run rspec spec/lib/test_spec.rb
I used bundler to initially install the gems, but I haven't been adamant about updating the Gemfile.

Comment: Does `test_spec.rb` or `spec_helper.rb` setup bundler (is there a `require 'bundler/setup'` in either of them)?

Comment: There is in spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looking further into `'bundler/setup'` thanks to Matt I found when adding `gem 'mongo'` to my Gemfile seemed to fix the problem.